# For each new line do something

Tags: vb.net, textbox, refresh, newline

i have a textbox called txtChat and i want that for every new line the textbox2 and textbox3 gets refreshed.. i dont know how to make thits "new line thing" or which commmand is the right one. Im looking for something like

```
For Each NewLine refresh textbox2&3
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to monitor the input into a textbox as the user types you could use the keypress event. The parameter e.KeyChar then corresponds to the keyboard key pressed by the user. If it is equal to vbCr you can conclude the user pressed enter. Your code should probably look something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    If e.KeyChar = vbCr Then
        'Refresh textboxes 2  and 3
    End If

End Sub
```

You would get into trouble though if, for example, the user copy-pasted something in, as the user will then not have entered a newline character.

As Dries says, you could use the textchange event, in which case you would have to check what the last character entered into the textbox is. Slightly confusingly, in this case, you would have to check if the text ends with a vbCrLf.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    If TextBox1.Text.EndsWith(vbCrLf) Then
        'Refresh textboxes 2 and 3
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the TextChange Event. 
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

It should point out what you're looking for (as far as I understand).